# Slider not looped, only once

Tags: jquery, loops, slider

am trying to get the jquery to make a full loop slider but just once loop ! Here is my code so far:

```
$('.slider .slide:first').addClass('active').fadeIn(200);

function rotate(index) {
    $('.slider .slide.active').removeClass('active').fadeOut(200, function () {
        $('.slider .slide:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('active').fadeIn(200);
    });
}

$('.slider-nav li a').click(function () {
    var index = $(this).parent().index('li');
    rotate(index);
    return false;
});

setInterval(function () {
    var $next = $('.slider .slide.active').next();

    if ($next.length == 100) $next = $('.slider .slide:first');

    rotate($next.index());
}, 2000);
```

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1/d3LVc/)

Comment: Please explain more your issue.

Comment: Can you see the jsfiddle ?

Comment: After last slide not skipe to first slide to show !

Comment: try with "if ($next.length == 0)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `count variable` and `modulus` it by using the `child element's length`

Try,

```
var xCnt = 1;

setInterval(function () { 
    rotate(xCnt % $('.slider .slide').length);
    xCnt += 1;
}, 2000);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d3LVc/1/)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you Rajaprabhu!

Comment: @BijanZand Sorry if I was annoying, but I didn't get your question.

Comment: @TimTimmy OP wants to do a cyclic slide transition.